# Cannot install any package with apt in Fedora

Tags: fedora, apt

When I try to install any package in Fedora, (for example, `sudo apt-get upgrade`), I see this error:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,814 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-10-base:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): cannot set security execution context for maintainer script: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): cannot set security execution context for maintainer script: Invalid argument
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new libc6:amd64 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-13+deb11u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `apt` is used in Debian and Ubuntu and related distros, but not in Fedora. [Use DNF instead](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-vs-apt/). See also [this link](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Differences_to_Ubuntu)

Comment: @sudous you could write that as an answer in my point of view

Comment: @sudodus Lot packages are not in dnf.

Comment: @Arian, Are you thinking of [`yum` or some GUI package manager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system)? Or are you thinking of `deb` program packages (intended for Debian/Ubuntu, and a method to use them in Fedora?

Comment: OP is actually using APT installed on Fedora. I don't think they are clueless about which package manager to use, I think they are having difficulty with the intent and purpose of using APT with Fedora. So far, all the answer except for @Sérgio seem focused on "apt isn't part of Fedora". The OP should add detail and explanation as to WHY they are using APT, what it seems to be failing on, and what they have tried. I.E. [how-to-ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6):

The  [APT-RPM](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch07s03s06.html) is unmaintained and broken, you should use `dnf` instead of `apt`.

Fedora docs: [Why is APT in the Fedora repositories?](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-vs-apt/#_why_is_apt_in_the_fedora_repositories)

> Warning

> APT can not be used to install packages on Fedora, you have to use DNF instead.

> The apt command on Fedora used to - until Fedora 32 - actually be APT-RPM, which basically mapped normal apt commands so that they worked with Fedora’s RPM package management system.

> However, APT-RPM is unmaintained, broken & insecure, and so was dropped in favour of shipping the actual Debian APT software. Since APT exclusively deals with .deb packages, the apt command can no longer be used to manage Fedora packages. Its purpose is now purely as a tool for people building packages for Debian-based distributions on a Fedora system.

Answer (score 3):

The "APT" family of tools comes from the Debian universe. In Fedora, we use a similar tool called "DNF" (previously, "Yum"). There are pluses and minuses to both, but from a user level (especially for basic functionality) they are effectively interchangeable. We have a cheat-sheet here: [APT command equivalents on Fedora with DNF](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-vs-apt/), but in short:

`apt upgrade` → `dnf upgrade`

`apt install` → `dnf install`

`apt remove` → `dnf remove`

`apt search` → `dnf search`

The main thing to watch out for is that package names in the Debian universe (particularly, development library names, but also other utilities and tools) do not necessarily match. So, you might find `sudo apt install apcalc` on Debian, and it turns out to be `sudo dnf install calc` on Fedora Linux.

As others have noted, there *is* an `apt` package in Fedora Linux, but that's there for the convenience of developers working to build Debian packages from their Fedora Linux systems. It's not meant for typical end-user use.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Rosetta

Comment: As always, Arch has great docs.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of apt in Fedora is be able to download package from Debian distributions , is not to install packages .
apt just read Debian like repos , not Fedora repos, therefore when you have a project that just do debian packages you can download it easy in Fedora .
for example jitsi, leap (riseup-vpn_0.19.11_amd64.deb, signal or slack

for example signal (https://signal.org/download/linux/)

as root:

1. Install official public software signing key

```
wget -O- https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
cat signal-desktop-keyring.gpg | tee -a /usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg > /dev/null
```

2. Add repository to your list of repositories

```
 echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' |\
 tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

3. download signal-desktop_x.xx.x_amd64.deb with

```
apt update 
apt-get download signal-desktop
```

## Warning wind up the next commands for other things may damage the system and make it unrecoverable .

4. install it on Fedora without check dependencies , as you may suspect **this is a big hack** and is not recommended neither official , but work for me in a very quick way .

```
 dpkg --force-depends -i signal-desktop_5.23.0_amd64.deb 
 desktop-file-install ./usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop
```